# Ember parent route redirection to child route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

My routes looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('index', { path: '/' }, function() {
        this.resource('label', { path: '/label' }, function() {
            this.route('notes', { path: '/:label_id' });
        });
        this.route('manage', { path: '/manage' });
    });
});
```

Users should only visit `label.notes` and `manage` routes. I'm trying to find solution how to implement redirection from `index` for example to `label.notes`. One of methods described in documentation is:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('label.notes', 0);
    }
});
```

Here is jsbin with full example http://jsbin.com/UnasOse/1/edit

This works if user navigates by clicking links, but if `manage` opened by url, or page updated user will be redirected to `notes`.

So, how to implement redirection only then user opens root url (`index`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the your current router mapping, you have the routes `index.manage` and `label.notes`.
When the page is refreshed in the `index.manage`, first it will transition to the parent route, in that case the `index`, and after to `manage`. But in you `index` you have the redirect, so the manage isn't processed.

Just remove of your mapping the `resource('index')` and update your manage route to reflect the new configuration, so link-to `index.manage` will become `manage`, and data-template-name=index/manage to manage etc.

The updated route mapping is the following:

```
App.Router.map(function () {    
  // this.route('index', { path: '/' }); generated by ember
  this.resource('label', { path: '/label' }, function() {
    this.route('notes', { path: '/:label_id' });
  });
  this.route('manage', { path: '/manage' });    
});
```

You can keep your IndexRoute, because ember create by default a `this.route('index', { path: '/' })`. So your IndexRoute will execute just when the user go to `http://yoursite.com/`

You can see that sample in action in this jsbin http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1024/edit

Comment: It works, but in that case I lose template nesting, I've updated my question with a link to jsbin http://jsbin.com/UnasOse/1/edit with example.

Comment: Hmm the routing behaves in the same way, like the previous. If you want to nesting the manage route, you can use this.resource('manage') ..., and put your new routes inside of the manage resource. Am I missing something?

Comment: My logic here is - 'index' resource renders common element - say toolbar with links, available in 'manage' and in 'label.notes', so I include them in 'index' resource. But open only toolbar (index) have no sense, and I want redirect in that case.

Comment: Why not use the `data-template-name=application` to render common elements? If you see my jsbin, I am using it.

Comment: Because these elements common only for `index` resource, also I have `login`, `singup` routes, which have its own templates without toolbar. I'll try to move routes from `index` to separate resource, and leave `index` always redirecting, this should work for me. Thanks for advises!

Comment: Fine, it works here's jsbin for final solution http://jsbin.com/UnasOse/2/edit I've separated my app from index route, index route now always redirect